# Failing to dyn_cast Expression pointer to DeclRefExpr in clang

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, libtooling

I m working on clang libtooling, I needed the left hand side of the assignment operation ,

So I used `VisitBinaryOperator(BinaryOperator *B)` to get the left hand side , I did some research on it and implemented in the following way

```
bool VisitBinaryOperator(BinaryOperator *B)
{
  if(B->isAssignmentOp())
{
Expr *E = B->getLHS();
  if(const clang::DeclRefExpr *lhs =  dyn_cast<clang::DeclRefExpr>(E))
  {
    cout<< "Count 1\n";
  }
}
    return true;
}
```

This is my sample program

```
#define abc ab
int ab[5];
int b[10];
int main()
{
b[0] = 0;
b[1] = b[0];
abc[1] = 0;
}
```

For this program `VisitBinaryOperator` function should go inside the if condition , as b[0],b[1],abc[1] are referred in the main function .

But control is not going inside only , and I m failing to debug it also .

Please Let me know the answer for this issue.

Comment: http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/clang-3-8-libtooling-cannot-visit-some-BinaryOperator-td4054719.html

Comment: @doptimusprime It didnt worked. when i give a integer variable like i = 10 , I can get the name of the variable. But when I give the array variable i[0] = 10, condition Itself is not being satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

You did everything correctly and Clang did it as well. The problem here is that `b[0]` (and other *LHS*s as well) are not `DeclRefExpr`. `b` is a `DeclRefExpr` and `b[0]` is an `ArraySubscriptExpr`.

If you print out the AST sub-tree for the first assignment, here is what you'll get:

```
    |-BinaryOperator 0x5601f96e8a30 <line:5:3, col:10> 'int' lvalue '='
    | |-ArraySubscriptExpr 0x5601f96e89f0 <col:3, col:6> 'int' lvalue
    | | |-ImplicitCastExpr 0x5601f96e89d8 <col:3> 'int *' <ArrayToPointerDecay>
    | | | `-DeclRefExpr 0x5601f96e8968 <col:3> 'int [10]' lvalue Var 0x5601f96e87f0 'b' 'int [10]'
    | | `-IntegerLiteral 0x5601f96e8988 <col:5> 'int' 0
    | `-IntegerLiteral 0x5601f96e8a10 <col:10> 'int' 0
```

As the result, if you want to get `DeclRefExpr` you need either get there manually (through `ArraySubscriptExpr` and `ImplicitCastExpr` expressions) or by using `RecursiveASTVisitor`.

I hope this information is useful. Happy hacking with Clang!